# Rollup failed to resolve alias(@) in vite

Tags: svelte, vite, sveltekit

> Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "@/sample.js" from
> "src/routes/random.svelte". This is most likely unintended because it
> can break your application at runtime. If you do want to externalize
> this module explicitly add it to `build.rollupOptions.external`

Vite config:

```
 plugins: [atomicPlugin(allAtomicCSSPaths)],
 resolve: {
   alias: {
  "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
   },
},
 server: {
   fs: {
  allow: [".."],
  },
},
```

Answer (score 6):

You can resolve this issue by:

```
plugins: [atomicPlugin(allAtomicCSSPaths)],
resolve: {
    alias: [{ find: "@", replacement: "/src" }],
},
server: {
    fs: {
        allow: [".."],
    },
},
```

For more You can see the complete issue discussion:
https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/279